# How to test / deploy Google Contextual Gadget

Tags: google-apps, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I am trying to create Gmail contextual gadget and am utterly confused regarding to testing / deployment. For side-bar gadgets I can simply put it into my web site and load from the Gmail setup. However, it appears that for contextual gadgets I need Google Apps domain. We do not use Google Apps - this new gadgets is for our customers. Any advice on best practices in developing Gmail Contextual Gadget will be greatly appreciated.